# Как не загружать изображения в скрытых блоках?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть скрытые блоки внутри которых много контента + изображений.
Как можно сделать, чтобы изображения загружались только когда блок становился видимым?

```
<div class="hidden">
    <img src="path/to/img">
</div>
```

И в определенные моменты

```
$('.block').removeClass('hidden')
```

Comment: Единственное что приходит в голову - совать ноды в `DOM` только когда блок необходимо показывать. Тогда картинки не будет подгружаться до этого момента.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос ваш код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="hidden">
    <img src="" data-src="path/to/img">
</div>
```

В момент удаления класса hidden пробегать по всем картинкам и менять значение src на путь из data-src.

```
const image = new Image()
image.src = $(this).attr('data-src')
image.onload = () => {
    $(this).attr('src', image.src)
}
```

В коде JQuery могут быть неточности, но суть, думаю, ясна. 
Можно изначально загружать в src превьюшку 10x10 пикселей и растягивать до нужной ширины. Это даст эффект размытого изображения.

Answer (score 0):

Можно разбить изображения на блоки и вызывать их, когда вам надо, через [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: но для этого нужно их засунуть в отдельные странички, а я могу управлять только текущей страницей, все эти картинки/данные получаю от сервера(